# Function in python is stopping my code from giving an output and no error messages are displaying?

Tags: python, python-3.9

I've narrowed it down to the elif part of my setup() function stopping my code from functioning as the first if statement runs fine when used, it also doesn't return any error messages when the code doesn't continue.

I've removed this function to ensure my other ones run as normal, which they do, which means it must be to do with this specifically?

Any help would really be appreciated, I've been at this for days and can't find find the problem, I'm probably being stupid and missing something simple.

This is also my first time asking a question here, if I've haven't given the necessary information or more is needed, apologies and please do ask.

Here's the function:

```
class votingSystem():

    def setup():
        setup = False
        while not setup:
            f1 = open('lib.py')
            search = 'abstain' 
            if search not in f1.read():
                setup = True
                with open('lib.py', 'w') as file:
                    file.write('abstain = 0' + '\n' * 5)
            elif search in f1.read():
                setup  = True
                with open('lib.py', 'w') as file:
                    file.write('\n\n\n\n' * 5)
   setup()
```

Comment: Did you mean to read from `f1` twice, in both the `if` and the `elif`? If you did, that's an unusual pattern and I would not recommend it. If you did not mean to, then replace the latter with a simple `else`. Also, do not give your function *and* your boolean variable the same name of `setup`.

Comment: Calling `read()` in the `if` statement exhausts the file content.  There is nothing left to read in the `elif` statement.  But you can really just use `else` here.

Comment: you need a `self` inside the function call -> `def setup(self):`

Comment: Thank you very much, swapped it to else instead of elif, working perfectly now.